# How can we import partial records in AWS glue job from DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We have large data storage ~200M in Dynamodb tables. We have snowflake dashboards which takes data from S3 parquet flles. Parquet files are generate using AWS glue jobs with crawlers.
Our glue jobs runs daily in morning and import data from AWS DynamoDB. My concern is crawler always crawles the whole dynamodb table.I need my crawler to get data from past 10 days only.
As the size of table's increasing rapidly the cost is also increasing.

Here is snippet of my python script used:

`datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dbname", table_name = "dynamodb_audit", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")`

Comment: Unless you have a column for "insertDate" or "lastChangeDate" and proper GSI on that there is little you can do about that. What *is* your table partitioning and indexing setup?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an index on the date. It is an audit table with a unique key as the primary key. It is like write-only table.

Comment: Then your goal is not achievable with dynamodb without scanning the entire table every time.

Comment: What if we have GSI ? How can we achieve this?

Comment: Then you could query the records where insertDate > someDate...

Answer (score 0):

You crawler doesn't need to read the entire table, it only needs to sample it. But keep in mind, the crawler is only used to create the schema, it does not provide you actual data.

As for your use-case, it seems you would only like to read 10 days worth of data into your Glue job. Glue cannot achieve that via the Spark Connector for DynamoDB, so you will have to resort to using Boto3 to read the last 10 days worth of data, and that depends if your tables schema is capable of providing such a query efficiently, which is unlikely.

#### My suggestion would be to do one of the following:

1. Rotate your table every 10 days, so the table only holds the data you require. This will mean very little change needed to your Glue job.
2. Stream the data into alternative tables, which again holds data for only 10 days, allowing you to still use your original table as you require by other applications and your Glue job can read from these temporary 10 day tables.
3. Create a GSI, which will allow you to read data from your table for the last 10 days efficiently, however, it would require that you use Boto3 to obtain the data using a `Query` API.